# Thymeleaf split table on different pages in pdf

Tags: java, html, kotlin, pdf, thymeleaf

I have a html template with table

```
<table id="people" border="1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr th:each="element : ${tableData}">
    <td th:text="${element.ID}">ID</td>
    <td th:text="${element.Name}">Name</td>
    <td th:text="${element.Salary}">Salary</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2»>Total salary</td>
    <td th:text="${totalSalary}">Salary</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

And here is the pdf generator:

```
public fun generate(map: Map<String, Any>, templateName: String) {
    val templateResolver = ClassLoaderTemplateResolver()
    templateResolver.suffix = ".html"
    templateResolver.templateMode = TemplateMode.HTML
    val templateEngine = TemplateEngine()
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver)
    val context = Context()
    context.setVariables(map)
    val html = templateEngine.process(templateName, context)

    generatePdfFromHtml(html, templateName)
}

private fun generatePdfFromHtml(html: String?, pdfName: String) {
    val outputFolder = "$pdfName.pdf"
    val outputStream: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(outputFolder)
    val renderer = ITextRenderer()
    renderer.fontResolver.addFont("fonts/TNR.ttf",  BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,
        BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED)
    renderer.setDocumentFromString(html)
    renderer.layout()
    renderer.createPDF(outputStream)
    outputStream.close()
}
```

I pass a list with data to this table and value of totalSalary. I want to limit number of raws on single pdf page. For example limit is 10, and if I pass list with 35 elements the table will be splitted to 4 pages. At this moment all raws just come in sequence. How can it be done with thymeleaf pdf converter?

Answer (score 1):

If you using iText HTML to PDF converter, you just need to properly craft your HTML source. Every 10 rows (or whatever your limit is) you may add the following style ...

```
<tr style="page-break-before: always">
   ...
</tr>
```

According to [HTML Page breaks](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it5kb/examples/html-page-breaks#HTMLPagebreaks-htmlpagebreaks) this style will add the page break for generated PDF.

Now, to generate such an HTML source with Thymeleaf you would need to use Thymeleaf [iteration index](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status). Check this index and when your loop passes yet another 10 entries add this style attribute to the following row. The code may look like ...

```
<tr th:each="element,iterStat : ${tableData}" th:styleappend="${iterStat.index%10 == 0}? 'page-break-before: always'">
    <td th:text="${element.ID}">ID</td>
    <td th:text="${element.Name}">Name</td>
    <td th:text="${element.Salary}">Salary</td>
</tr>
```

Please note, I didn't run this code and it is provided for your reference only, not as a copy&paste solution, to get an idea of the approach you should take.